# Unexpected output of multithreaded C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock, race-condition

I'm studying concurrency in C++ and I'm trying to implement a multithreaded callback registration system. I came up with the following code, which is supposed to accept registration requests until an event occurs. After that, it should execute all the registered callbacks in order with which they were registered. The registration order doesn't have to be deterministic.
The code doesn't work as expected. First of all, it rarely prints the "Pushing callback with id" message. Secondly, it sometimes hangs (a deadlock caused by a race condition, I assume). I'd appreciate help in figuring out what's going on here. If you see that I overcomplicate some parts of the code or misuse some pieces, please also point it out.

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

class CallbackRegistrar{
public:
    void registerCallbackAndExecute(std::function<void()> callback) {
        if (!eventTriggered) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(callbackMutex);
            auto saved_id = callback_id;
            std::cout << "Pushing callback with id " << saved_id << std::endl;
            registeredCallbacks.push(std::make_pair(callback_id, callback));
            ++callback_id;
            callbackCond.wait(lock, [this, saved_id]{return releasedCallback.first == saved_id;});
            releasedCallback.second();
            callbackExecuted = true;
            eventCond.notify_one();
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }
    }
    void registerEvent() {
        eventTriggered = true;
        while (!registeredCallbacks.empty()) {
            releasedCallback = registeredCallbacks.front();
            callbackCond.notify_all();
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(eventMutex);
            eventCond.wait(lock, [this]{return callbackExecuted;});
            callbackExecuted = false;
            registeredCallbacks.pop();
        }
    }
private:
    std::queue<std::pair<unsigned, std::function<void()>>> registeredCallbacks;
    bool eventTriggered{false};
    bool callbackExecuted{false};
    std::mutex callbackMutex;
    std::mutex eventMutex;
    std::condition_variable callbackCond;
    std::condition_variable eventCond;
    unsigned callback_id{1};
    std::pair<unsigned, std::function<void()>> releasedCallback;
};

int main()
{
    CallbackRegistrar registrar;
    std::thread t1(&CallbackRegistrar::registerCallbackAndExecute, std::ref(registrar), []{std::cout << "First!\n";});
    std::thread t2(&CallbackRegistrar::registerCallbackAndExecute, std::ref(registrar), []{std::cout << "Second!\n";});
    
    registrar.registerEvent();
    
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (!eventTriggered)` isn't synchronized. If you don't want to lock the mutex before checking `eventTriggered` then make `eventTriggered` atomic.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thanks, this is probably one of the problems, but when I move the lock to before the if statement, I'm still getting the same output

Comment: I haven't really dug into it, it was just the first observation I made. :)

Comment: Please document which data is shared between threads and which mutex is used to control access to them. Also, for a condition variable, document which mutex it's to be used with. Getting these things straight is in my experience fundamental.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the multipurpose function `registerCallbackAndExecute`. Why is it executing the callback? Also, `while (!registeredCallbacks.empty())` in `registerEvent()` is also not synchronized, so there's another race.

Comment: And the queue -- that's accessed by multiple execution threads, is also accessed without holding a mutex lock. The whole thing needs to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: @TedLyngmo From what I can see the intent of the function seems to be to execute straight away under certain conditions, and under other conditions to queue up the callback to be called at a later time. Parts of the design look like the aim is for some sort of async work queue that executes jobs straight away if there is nothing pending, but it seems to be linked to some external event... I'm not sure really

Comment: Fwiw, are you using g++ or clang++?  If you are, you could compile with `-g -fsanitize=thread`. It _should_ find some issues in the program and hopefully point directly at them.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.
The intention was to write a callback registration mechanism. Before a certain one-time event occurs, callbacks are pushed to the queue. Then, once the event occurs, all the callbacks should be executed in order that they've been pushed to the queue and by the same thread that registered them. All further calls to registerCallbackAndExecute (after the event had happened) should be immediately executed with no additional registration

Comment: I was using onlinegdb.com, I'm not sure what compiler it uses. It's really just for learning purposes. I didn't think about the sanitizers, that's some good advice, I'll see if this brings more insight

Comment: *I'm studying concurrency in C++ and I'm trying to implement a multithreaded callback registration system* -- Multithreaded programming in C++ is not easy.  That's why MT programmers often have salaries much higher than the programmer who works on single-threaded applications.  Simply on the "I'm studying" level means that there will be much more things that will surprise you when it comes to MT programming, and you really won't know these things until much experience is gained.

Comment: @user6646922 I didn't realise that you wanted the callbacks to be called in the thread in which they were registered. The code I provided before won't do that, I have updated my answer with something closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer has been edited in response to more information being provided by the OP in a comment, the edit is at the bottom of the answer.*

Along with the excellent suggestions in the comments, the main problem that I have found in your code is with the `callbackCond` condition variable wait condition that you have set up. What happens if `releasedCallback.first` does not equal `savedId`?

When I have run your code (with a thread-safe queue and `eventTriggered` as an atomic) I found that the problem was in this wait function, if you put a print statement in that function you will find that you get something like this:

```
releasedCallback.first: 0, savedId: 1
```

This then waits forever.

In fact, I've found that the condition variables used in your code aren't actually needed. You only need one, and it can live inside the thread-safe queue that you are going to build after some searching ;)

After you have the thread-safe queue, the code from above can be reduced to:

```cpp
class CallbackRegistrar{
public:
  using NumberedCallback = std::pair<unsigned int, std::function<void()>>;

  void postCallback(std::function<void()> callback) {

    if (!eventTriggered)
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
      auto saved_id = callback_id;
      std::cout << "Pushing callback with id " << saved_id << std::endl;
      registeredCallbacks.push(std::make_pair(callback_id, callback));
      ++callback_id;
    }
    else
    {
      while (!registeredCallbacks.empty())
      {
        NumberedCallback releasedCallback;
        registeredCallbacks.waitAndPop(releasedCallback);
        releasedCallback.second();
      }
      callback();
    }
  }
  void registerEvent() {
    eventTriggered = true;
  }
private:
  ThreadSafeQueue<NumberedCallback> registeredCallbacks;
  std::atomic<bool> eventTriggered{false};
  std::mutex mutex;
  unsigned int callback_id{1};
};

int main()
{
  CallbackRegistrar registrar;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&CallbackRegistrar::postCallback, 
                                  std::ref(registrar), 
                                  [i]{std::cout << std::to_string(i) <<"\n";}
                                  ));
  }

  registrar.registerEvent();

  for (auto& thread : threads)
  {
    thread.join();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this does exactly what you want, but it doesn't deadlock. It's a good starting point in any case, but you need to bring your own implementation of ThreadSafeQueue.

### Edit

This edit is in response to the comment by the OP stating that *"once the event occurs, all the callbacks should be executed in [the] order that they've been pushed to the queue and **by the same thread that registered them**"*.

This was not mentioned in the original question post. However, if that is the required behaviour then we need to have a condition variable wait in the `postCallback` method. I think this is also the reason why the OP had the condition variable in the `postCallback` method in the first place.

In the code below I have made a few edits to the callbacks, they now take input parameters. I did this to print some useful information while the code is running so that it is easier to see how it works, and, importantly how the condition variable wait is working.

The basic idea is similar to what you had done, I've just trimmed out the stuff you didn't need.

```cpp
class CallbackRegistrar{
public:
  using NumberedCallback = std::pair<unsigned int, std::function<void(int, int)>>;

  void postCallback(std::function<void(int, int)> callback, int threadId) {

    if (!m_eventTriggered)
    {
      // Lock the m_mutex
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

      // Save the current callback ID and push the callback to the queue
      auto savedId = m_currentCallbackId++;
      std::cout << "Pushing callback with ID " << savedId << "\n";
      m_registeredCallbacks.push(std::make_pair(savedId, callback));

      // Wait until our thread's callback is next in the queue,
      // this will occur when the ID of the last called callback is one less than our saved callback.
      m_conditionVariable.wait(lock, [this, savedId, threadId] () -> bool
      {
        std::cout << "Waiting on thread " << threadId << " last: " << m_lastCalledCallbackId << ", saved - 1: " << (savedId - 1) << "\n";
        return (m_lastCalledCallbackId == (savedId - 1));
      });

      // Once we are finished waiting, get the callback out of the queue
      NumberedCallback retrievedCallback;
      m_registeredCallbacks.waitAndPop(retrievedCallback);

      // Update last callback ID and call the callback
      m_lastCalledCallbackId = retrievedCallback.first;
      retrievedCallback.second(m_lastCalledCallbackId, threadId);

      // Notify one waiting thread
      m_conditionVariable.notify_one();
    }
    else
    {
      // If the event is already triggered, call the callback straight away
      callback(-1, threadId);
    }
  }

  void registerEvent() {
    // This is all we have to do here.
    m_eventTriggered = true;
  }

private:
  ThreadSafeQueue<NumberedCallback> m_registeredCallbacks;
  std::atomic<bool> m_eventTriggered{ false};
  std::mutex m_mutex;
  std::condition_variable m_conditionVariable;
  unsigned int m_currentCallbackId{ 1};
  std::atomic<unsigned int> m_lastCalledCallbackId{ 0};
};
```

The main function is as above, except I am creating 100 threads instead of 10, and I have made the callback print out information about how it was called.

```cpp
for (int createdThreadId = 0; createdThreadId < 100; createdThreadId++)
{
  threads.push_back(std::thread(&CallbackRegistrar::postCallback,
                                std::ref(registrar),
                                [createdThreadId](int registeredCallbackId, int callingThreadId)
                                {
                                  if (registeredCallbackId < 0)
                                  {
                                    std::cout << "Callback " << createdThreadId;
                                    std::cout << " called immediately, from thread: " << callingThreadId << "\n";
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                    std::cout << "Callback " << createdThreadId;
                                    std::cout << " called from thread " << callingThreadId;
                                    std::cout << " after being registered as " << registeredCallbackId << "\n";
                                  }
                                },
                                createdThreadId));
}
```

I am not entirely sure why you want to do this, as it seems to defeat the point of having multiple threads, although I may be missing something there. But, regardless, I hope this helps you to understand better the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer :) I searched for thread safety of stl containers before writing this code and I thought std::queue would be good enough for my use case. I'll search some more then.
I'm still pretty confused why the code doesn't reliably print the "Pushing callback with id " part, when there's no deadlock in a particular run

Comment: Not sure, there is some overhead in creating the threads. So, if you are only making two it’s possible `registerEvent` is called before the threads start executing. I should have mentioned that I increased the number of threads up to 10 to test this.

Comment: @user6646922 -- `std::queue` is not thread safe, and neither are most, if not all of the STL containers.   Look at it this way -- why should a C++ programmer pay for the overhead of thread-safety if they are writing single-threaded applications?  That goes against the [philosophy of C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/Zero-overhead_principle).

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with this code some more, I found out why the "Pushing callback with id " part was rarely printed. It's because the call to `registrar.registerEvent` from the main thread was usually faster than the calls to `registerCallbackAndExecute` from separate threads. Because of that, the condition `if (!eventTriggered)` was almost never fulfilled (`eventTriggered` had been set to true in the `registerEvent` method) and hence all calls to `registerCallbackAndExecute` were falling into the else branch and executing straightaway.
Then, the program sometimes also didn't finish, because of a race condition between `registerEvent` and `registerCallbackAndExecute`. Sometimes, `registerEvent` was being called after the check `if (!eventTriggered)` but before pushing the callback to the queue. Then, `registerEvent` completed instantly (as the queue was empty) while the thread calling `registerCallbackAndExecute` was pushing the callback to the queue. The latter thread then kept waiting forever for the event (that had already happened) to happen.